# remove 0 and add ' ' in every number in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
0813466, 0813472, 0813473, 0813474, 0813475, 0813476, 0813477, 0813478, 0813479,
```

I want to remove all zero values ​​in front of my number and add quotation marks to each number, so that my data will become

```
'813466', '813472', '813473', '813474', '813475', '813476', '813477', '813478', '813479'
```

Comment: Is that a column? A row? Please add more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove traling `0` form left side by [`Series.str.lstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html), thank you @yatu for mention it:

> Those have to be strings though, otherwise they woulnd't have those 0s

```
df['col'].str.lstrip('0')
```

Comment: Those have to be strings though, otherwise they woulnd't have those `0`s